# PHP Запись массива в строку рекурсией

Tags: php, рекурсия

есть такой массив и функция, при обычном выводе (echo) всё корректно выводится, но при записывании в строку массив записывается в не понятном порядке, пример ниже

```
    $arr = array (
    "2018.10.20" => array (
        "15:00" => array (
            "select_place_of_performance" => "Событие 1",
            "data_concerts" => "2018.10.20",
            "time_concerts" => "15:00",
            "time_sound_check" => "13:00",
            "select_performers 1" => array (
                0 => "Вася Пупкин 1",
                1 => "Вася Пупкин 2",
                2 => "Вася Пупкин 3",
            ),
        ),
        "18:00" => array (
            "select_place_of_performance" => "Событие 2",
            "data_concerts" => "2018.10.20",
            "time_concerts" => "18:00",
            "time_sound_check" => "13:00",
            "select_performers 2" => array (
                0 => "Вася Пупкин 1",
                1 => "Вася Пупкин 2",
                2 => "Вася Пупкин 3",
            ),
        ),
    ),
    "2018.10.22" => array (
        "22:00" => array (
            "select_place_of_performance" => "Событие 3",
            "data_concerts" => "2018.10.22",
            "time_concerts" => "22:00",
            "time_sound_check" => "13:00",
            "select_performers 3" => array (
                0 => "Вася Пупкин 1",
                1 => "Вася Пупкин 2",
                2 => "Вася Пупкин 3",
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

если записывать массив в строку

```
function array_str ($array, $name_array = null) {
    $str = "";
    foreach ($array as $key =>$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $str .= $key;
            $str .= "<br>";
            array_str ($value);
        } else {
            $str .= $key;
            $str .= "<br>";
        }   
    }
    echo $str;
}
```

то выводится не так как ожидается

```
0
1
2
select_place_of_performance
data_concerts
time_concerts
time_sound_check
select_performers 1
0
1
2
select_place_of_performance
data_concerts
time_concerts
time_sound_check
select_performers 2
15:00
18:00
0
1
2
select_place_of_performance
data_concerts
time_concerts
time_sound_check
select_performers 3
22:00
2018.10.20
2018.10.22
```

при выводе оператором echo

```
function array_str ($array, $name_array = null) {
    foreach ($array as $key =>$value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo $key;
            echo "<br>";
            array_str ($value);
        } else {
            echo $key;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

всё выводится корректно

```
2018.10.20
15:00
select_place_of_performance
data_concerts
time_concerts
time_sound_check
select_performers 1
0
1
2
18:00
select_place_of_performance
data_concerts
time_concerts
time_sound_check
select_performers 2
0
1
2
2018.10.22
22:00
select_place_of_performance
data_concerts
time_concerts
time_sound_check
select_performers 3
0
1
2
```

Comment: Все правильно выводится. А как хотелось?

Comment: добавил примеры вывода выше, то есть даты "2018.10.20" и "2018.10.22" если собирать их строкой в переменную $str а потом выводить echo $str то даты выводятся в конце всего, короче не в том порядке, в реультате если записывать эту строку в файл то всё перепутывается

Comment: и где там ваш код вывода в строку то? я тут вижу только локальную переменную `str` область видимости которой не предполагает вообще построение чего-либо

Comment: Прогоняйте в цикле и раскладывайте, с помощью `join`.

Comment: всё и так прогоняется в цикле рекурсией

Answer (score 0):

Замените вашу функцию `array_str` такой

```
function array_str($array) {
    $str = "";
    foreach ($array as $key =>$value) {
        $str .= $key;
        $str .= "<br>";
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $str .= array_str($value);
        }   
    }
    return $str;
}

echo array_str($arr);
```

Comment: @Макс Тогда отметьте ответ как верный